# Podio delete workspace API giving forbidden error

Tags: podio

I have created one workspace from the API and I want to delete the same workspace using the same api and the same user which we used to create workspace using API. But Podio is giving 'PodioForbiddenError', I am not sure that why it is having forbidden error when we are using same user.

I am calling following API:

```
PodioSpace::delete($space_id);
```

And it is giving following error:

```
PodioForbiddenError
in Podio.php line 319
at Podio::request('DELETE', '/space/5295098', array()) in Podio.php line 358
at Podio::delete('/space/5295098') in PodioSpace.php line 87
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be trusted partner to be able to call that method from API.

You need special privilege for your API Client/Secret to get that. For normal API Client `delete space` call is blocked. The increase of trust level needed for this operation is only granted to trusted companies and individuals, e.g. partners, and the verification is done by our customer care team, you can contact them by mail: support@podio.com.

Comment: We contacted with the support and they are asking that what is our current trust level so how I can get our current trust level?

Comment: It's ok to reply that you don't know your current trust level (default value is 0)

Comment: I contacted with the support that I do not know the trust level and they said that post the query on stack overflow for asking how to get trust level using the API.

Comment: Default trust level is `None`